# How can I express "you are funny" without sounding sarcastic?

Tags: word-request

My friends make hilarious jokes and I want to praise them. I wanted to say you are funny but I suspect that can be understood as being ironic. How should I avoid that?

Comment: IMHO it's not really possible for *You are funny* to be misinterpreted as a negative statement unless that was intended in the first place, so I think this question is essentially trying to address a ***non-problem***. And anyone who actually *answers* the question as presented is at risk of giving you the seriously mistaken impression your choice of phrasing makes some difference here. Obviously the person you're talking to knows perfectly well how good your command of English is, *and* they know how likely it is that you're being sarcastic. The question is all but pointless.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ray Liotta would beg to differ! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_DwZfyXAXI

Comment: @ice1000 *Sounding Sarcastic* (at least for a new user of English) is not an easy feat to pull off. Additionally, `You are funny` does not sound sarcastic on its own. Consider: 'Yes, I really want to drench myself in this cold rain', 'No, I don't mind getting cut off in a queue at all'. 'Oh, I love getting interrupted while relaxing'. You may want to improve your question with better examples if your query is about sarcasm alone

Comment: @MarcInManhattan That was the very first thing I thought of!

Comment: Are you genuinely laughing, then saying someone is funny will not be misinterpreted. If someone tells a bad joke, and no one in the group is laughing, smiling, or giggling, then the phrase "You're funny" could come off as a wry observation. Someone might even think that was an amusing thing to say. Timing is everything. The Goodfellas' movie reference is an example of someone *not* being sarcastic but of someone **paying a compliment**.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan: Terrific scene, that - but actually it just proves the point I made in my first comment. Ray Liotta's character is completely flummoxed by the fact that Joe Pesci's character *appears* to misunderstand Liotta's obviously appreciative ***That's [your anecdote] really funny!*** And the main *reason* he's so thrown is he simply can't see how Pesci could have misunderstood him (which of course he *didn't* - Pesci's just messin' with him! :) But thanks for the link, anyway. I didn't know until just now that the extras weren't told about the "ad-libbed" joke, adding to the tension.

Comment: (Also, I'm a big fan of Liotta, but I haven't watched that scene for years. I'd forgotten how *young* he is there, and of course Joe Pesci had already established his ability to play *really* dangerous "superficially relaxed & friendly" characters, so I find Liotta's consternation even more incredibly convincing. He comes across as just a terrified inexperienced kid in that scene!)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, my comment was to a large extent facetious :) (though I think relevant to this question). And yes, Liotta was a great actor; it was sad to lose him last year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While sarcasm is mostly in the tone of your words, I would actually opt for "hilarious" over "funny." The latter is rarely said to a person directly, while the former certainly can be. If you're unsure if your point will be understood, just add "seriously" afterwards.

Otherwise, you can opt for a colloquialism, like "you really crack me up."

> "You're hilarious. You really crack me up! No, serious!"